# portal_catalog unique ids for both Archetypes and Dexterity content

Tags: plone, archetypes, uid, dexterity

I am querying portal_catalog to populate a vocabulary with (UID, Title) tuples. The site has both Archetypes and Dexterity content.

```
brains = portal_catalog.searchResults(path={ "query": site_physical_path + "/" + folder_name },
               portal_type=["foobar.app.courseinfo", "Folder"] )
```

Look like Dexterity content is not given proper UID and in fact all Dexterity items have the same UID (it's not even an invalid value).

```
 ('29550a9a-5e6c-4593-8bee-9db11f29b934', u'xxx dexterity'), ('29550a9a-5e6c-4593-8bee-9db11f29b934', u'yyy dexterity'),
```

What's the best strategy to have unique ids across both Archetypes and Dexterity content in portal_catalog to be used as a look-up-able content id key?

Comment: I believe 29550a9a-5e6c-4593-8bee-9db11f29b934 is a valid uuid; however, having multiple objects with the same idea is obviously not right...

Comment: Can you please provide the configuration for your Dexterity types, and your Plone and Dexterity versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably acquiring the UID from the container of the Dexterity items.

As of Dexterity 1.1, all Dexterity items should get their own UUID as long as plone.uuid is present, which should always be the case in Plone 4.1 and above. Make sure you run the upgrade step to add UUIDs to existing items that don't have them.

Comment: Is upgrade step something else besides (re)installing Dexterity as 1.1?

Comment: Ok. Reinstalling Dexterity 1.1 - there must be something else undocumented involved

Comment: Manually running portal_setup -> upgrades -> plone.app.dexterity -> show old upgrades - Add missing UUIDs to Dexterity content (4 → 5) seems to do the trick

Comment: The upgrade step should have been runnable via a button in the Add-ons control panel like usual.